# How can I search for a file that contains a pattern and then search within all those files with another pattern?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

Basically, I want to do something like:

```
Locate log4j.xml
```

which will give me over 20 results. Then I want to search within all these files for "iwjboss".

Is there a command that locates and then finds text within all these files bearing in mind that I don't know the directory of all the log4j.xml files?

Answer (score 1):

Doing something with the result of something is achieved like this:

```
grep iwjboss `locate log4j.xml`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a command it is called `find`.

Try this command for find and grep combined:

```
find . -name "log4j.xml" -exec grep "iwjboss" '{}' \;
```